# Install MacOS without screen on iMac

Tags: imac, screen

I want to install macOS on an old iMac 21.5 from mid-2011, but the issue is the screen is completely broken.
When I opened the iMac, the screen accidentally fell onto my table.
The LCD connector is broken, and I think the LCD itself is too.
I have a cheap Thunderbolt to HDMI that does not give me output when starting the iMac.
The HDD is formatted, and I do not know how to install macOS without a screen.
I do not have the money to buy a replacement screen.

How would I install macOS?

Comment: Take the hard drive out, install the OS with another machine, put the hard drive back in?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use a second monitor connected to the Thunderbolt 2 port on the back of the iMac, and you *can* make it the primary monitor. Unfortunately, the settings to do this require MacOS to be installed and you going into Settings to adjust which if the two monitors are which. So you need the primary, now damaged monitor to work, in order to do this.

One option is to find a used, discarded iMac 21.5" and take the cable and screen from that. These are donated and tossed out all the time.

Comment: Depending on your geographical location [MacPartsOnline](https://www.macpartsonline.com/) may be a good source for the replacement screen. _Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with MacPartsOnline in any way._

Answer (score 0):

If you are near an Apple Store, I would [make an appointment there](https://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/) first.

It might save you having to buy hardware if they can use the hardware they have on site to get your Mac to a state where it is usable with an external display.